# How to embed an Android library (AAR file) into a capacitor plugin?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

The issue is already answered for iOS:
[How to embed framework in capacitor plugin for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58045726/how-to-embed-third-party-framework-on-ionic-capacitor-custom-plugin)

For Android, I get issues when I add an aar file to the capacitor plugin by creating a new module. After publishing my capacitor plugin via npm and integrating it into an ionic app, the aar library cannot be found anymore.

Answer (score 7):

As done on iOs, we do practically the same thing here. But, using Android Studio and gradle instead of xcode and cocoapods.
Ok, but first things first.

When the command `npx @capacitor/cli plugin:generate` is issued, what the CLI does is to start a folder containing a cocoa pod for iOs and a gradle plugin for Android. You can see this on the image below.

[image: Plugin folder showing all the files inside it]

With the above command issued, there will be a ios and android folders inside you generated plugin folder. If this checks, open you android studio and select the option to open a android studio project, selecting the **android** folder to fulfil this procedure. You can select this option on the initial screen, like showed on the next image.

[image: Initial screen o android studio showing the option to open a project]

With the project opened, if all went well you'll se your android studio showing a screen like this

[image: Zoomed version of the files pane of Android Studio and gradle log showing that the project was successfully opened]

Now, lets add the plugin files. To do this, right click the android java module and select the "Open Module settings" option, as shown on the next image.

[image: Menu showed by the action of right clicking the android java module]

With the following screen opened, we need to add a module here that contains our jar/aar dependencies. To do that, just click on the + sign that is showed above.

[image: Plus sign highlighted]

On the new module screen, if you scroll down there will be a "Import .JAR/.AAR package", like shown above.

[image: new module screen showing the referred option]

After that, locate you aar package. The result will be the following.

[image: aar package imported]

Click finish and the next screen will appear. If not, hit the apply button in this same screen.

[image: module added screen]

Since my module has a dependency, I'll repeat this part of the tutorial.

Next, we need to add our recently added modules as dependencies of the android module. On the same screen, click on the dependencies option and on the plus sign of the "declared dependencies" pane.

[image: Plus sign of the declared dependencies highlighted]

The following screen will show. We need to select the 3rd option, since what we did early was adding a module.

[image: Result of the plus sign click]

Now, lets select our module. Its simple, just mark it and click ok. Since I have to, as said before, I'll check both of them.

[image: add module dependency screen showing the dependencies to add]

If this step went well, you should have now you android module with one more dependency (or two in my case). The image bellow show that.

[image: module dependencies showing the new ones]

Hit apply and close this window. Gradle will rebuild your plugin project on the background and after that,since I know kotlin better, I'll convert my project to kotlin. If you wish, this can be done as shown on the next image, but is not mandatory.

[image: kotlin first steps to convert]

With all the above done correctly, you can now import your lib on the TestPlugin.kt (or .java if you didnt use kotlin). For reference, the image bellow show the minimum implementation for my plugin.

[image: minimum kotlin implementation of my plugin]

In the plugin folder, we are done. Pack it using npm and install on you app.

Next, to the plugin works properly, we need to add its class on the MainActivity of the app that you'll be using it.

[image: Main activity of the app showing the add our newly created plugin]

Now, to make it work, i'm not 100% sure that this is the correct way to do it, but since it works I do this way. The way I do is to add the plugin modules on the android module of the app via script. I think i am missing something on the gradle plugin implementation, but since it works.....

To do this, access, on your app, the android/settings.gradle file and append this:
[image: sdk add]

Please note that depending on the changes that you do, the settings.gradle file will be rewritten. Do a script to keep the info always there or check it before build.

Thats it, please comment if you know another way to this next step or in any another if there is a better approach. And, if this answer is useful, please thumbs it up, since this implementation, when finished and working, made me cry a little (of happiness, of course).

Comment: On android 3.6 the "module settings" is under the File menu (on the top) with the name "Project structure"

Comment: Unfortunately, none of this works in 2021 any more.  Or at the very least, you can't follow the steps because Android Studio has moved everything around in the newer versions.

Comment: Android studio has changed so much, these steps can't be followed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this. What I did was create a Capacitor plugin using the command "npm init @capacitor/plugin". The issue was that there was an error when including the .aar library within the plugin, as it compiles as a .aar library on its own. You have to place the .aar library inside /android/libs of both the plugin and the project, and in the plugin's build.gradle file, add it as "compileOnly files('libs/[lib_name].aar')" instead of an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

it is very strange, that till now there is no guide on how to embed a AAR file in to a Capacitor plugin in the official Capacitor documentation, as it is a very common use case why one would create a Capacitor plugin. Especially as in other multi-platform frameworks (Cordova, react-native, Xamarin) it is very straight forward and well documented.

I have tested 2 methods, which both seem more or less equivalent, as both require for you to also update the Android project, which is consuming the plugin.

**1. Create an Android module, which is added to the Android project**

a. Create the AAR module

```
my-module/
  ├── build.gradle
  └── my.aar

// my-module/build.gradle
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('my.aar'))
```

b. Add the dependency to the Capacitor plugin

```
// capacitor-plugin/android/build.gradle
dependencies {
  implementation project(":my-module")
}
```

c. Update the Android project and add the reference to my-module

```
// ionic-capacitor-project/android/settings.gradle
include ':my-module'
project(':my-module').projectDir = new File('path/to/my-module')
```

**2. Add the AAR file to a maven repository**

You can also add the AAR file to a maven repository, which is available only on the local disk, or in a private repo on the internet/network, or to some public repository like maven-central.

I have tested creating a local maven repository.

a. Create the local maven repository

```
my-repo
└── com
    └── package
        └── my
            └── 1.0.0
                ├── my-1.0.0.aar
                └── my-1.0.0.pom

//com/package/my/1.0.0/my-1.0.0.pom
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>my</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

b. Add the dependency to the Capacitor plugin

```
// capacitor-plugin/android/build.gradle
dependencies {
  implementation "com.package:my:1.0.0@aar"
}
```

c. Update the Android project and add the reference to my-repo

```
// ionic-capacitor-project/android/build.gradle
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url uri("/path/to/my-repo") }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

**Conclusion**

I did not find any way to include the AAR file directly in to the Capacitor plugin, without the need to update the Android project, which is consuming the plugin.