# Ionic how to open your app with shake when you app is in the background?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, shake

I am building an emergency app, and one of the features is to open the app on shake, now I understand that app must be in the background running.

and I am using cordova-background-mode and cordova shake
and the everything works,

however when the phone is on the home screen(the app is just minimized).
the app does not launch when I shake, but when I reopen the app by tapping on its icon, it does show that a shake event occurred and opens another app that I am using to test.

How can I get it to open the app on shake when the app is in the background?

### Here is my code

```
this.platform.ready().then((e) => {
      this.backgroundMode.enable();
      this.backgroundMode.setEnabled(true);

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

        this.shake.startWatch().subscribe(() => {
          console.log(`watching...${e}`);
          alert('shake');
          const options: AppLauncherOptions = {
          }

           if(this.platform.is('ios')) {
             options.uri = 'fb://'
           } else {
             options.packageName = 'com.facebook.katana'
           }

           this.appLauncher.canLaunch(options).then((launch:Boolean)=>{
             if(launch){
               this.appLauncher.launch(options).then(()=>{
                 alert('Launched')
               },
               (err)=>{
                alert(JSON.stringify(err))
               })
             }else{
               alert(JSON.stringify("unable to launch app"));
             }
           },(err)=>{
             alert(JSON.stringify(err));
           })  

          });
```

## Edit

this is my code and it works, however the problem is, if I open another app, i.e whatsapp but it can be any app, and close it, and then if I shake the phone, it opens the last app I was using instead of launching my app.

```
 startBackgroundMode(){          

    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.backgroundMode.overrideBackButton();           

    this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(value => {
        this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();  
        this.shakePhone();   
    });
}
shakePhone(){
  this.shake.startWatch().subscribe(() => {
    console.log(`watching...`);                      
    this.openApp();

    });
}
  openApp(){  

    const options: AppLauncherOptions = {
    }
    options.packageName = 'this is my app's package name'


  this.appLauncher.launch(options);

  }
```

Comment: Are you using ionic 4?

Comment: yes I am using ionic 4 with angular 8

Comment: you could integrate ionic capacitor and build a plugin that implements this resource natively. If you want I could post an answer with the links to make your own plugin with some learnings that I had

Comment: @igor that would be great thanks

Comment: I would like to point out, that the app does watch for shaking when the app is in the background, I am just battling to launch my app when its in the background. 
if I make the options.packageName to my app's package name then it opens that most recently opend app, but if I make the options.package name equal to com.facebook.katana for example then that works perfectly

Comment: I see, in this case I think my approach would have a bigger workload since you are already using a plenty of cordova plugins. I will post just to point a different method then.

Answer (score 1):

Various APIs like playing media or tracking GPS position in background might not work while in background even the background mode is active. To fix such issues the plugin provides a method to disable most optimizations done by Android/CrossWalk.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('activate', function() {
   cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations(); 
});
```

Note: Calling the method led to increased resource and power consumption.

Also need to use following

The plugin fires an event each time its status has been changed. These events are enable, disable, activate, deactivate and failure.

also need to check  this.shake.startWatch() in background activated mode

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('EVENT', function);
```

To remove an event listeners:

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.un('EVENT', function);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not the right way which you are trying. If you could employ *java* in order to develop your application then it was possible to use the `SensorManager` to detect a shake. Now you are working with *ionic* and the solution is taking advantage of [`device-motion`](https://caniuse.com/#search=Accelerometer) plugin.

**Note** that solutions like *ionic* are not as powerful as main development environment (java or kotlin with android studio) although they are more strong at interface design since they take advantage of browser based applications (web kit). So you have to consider [browser restrictions](https://caniuse.com/#search=Accelerometer) too, so employing sth like [*devicemotion* `EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation#Processing_motion_events) may not work on all operating systems.

If you are working on an important application choose the main solution to avoid restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you are using ionic 4, one way to achieve this result is by developing one custom plugin, but with ionic capacitor instead of cordova. Capacitor made easier to build your custom plugins and makes the native code more accessible for those who hasnt built any plugins yet.

The links below show how you implement a custom plugin for both ios and android.
[How to embed third party framework on ionic capacitor custom plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58045726/how-to-embed-third-party-framework-on-ionic-capacitor-custom-plugin/58749993#58749993) 
[How to embed an Android library (AAR file) into a capacitor plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068585/how-to-embed-an-android-library-aar-file-into-a-capacitor-plugin/59392621#59392621)

I point this solution as a alternative. I know that the workload would be much higher and that the project already have plenty of cordova plugins.