# How to register a local Ionic Capacitor plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I am working on a private capacitor plugin for android and ios but the official guide finished by saying upload to npm to use your plugin, I do not want to upload it to a publicly available resource.

How do you register a local capacitor plugin for both ios/android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You dont need to publish on npm to install it. You could do "npm pack" on your plugin folder and later on your app folder "npm install ../my-package/my-package-0.0.1.tgz"

Also, I answered a similar questions about making plugins. Please look:

[How to embed third party framework on ionic capacitor custom plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58045726/how-to-embed-third-party-framework-on-ionic-capacitor-custom-plugin)

[How to embed an Android library (AAR file) into a capacitor plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068585/how-to-embed-an-android-library-aar-file-into-a-capacitor-plugin/59392621#59392621)

Comment: don't even need to pack, can just install from the folder